Rational curves in $\Bbb P^1\times \Bbb P^1$
Let $\Bbb P^1$ be the complex projective line and consider the surface $X=\Bbb P^1\times \Bbb P^1$. The second integral (co)homology group of $X$ is $\Bbb Z^2$ generated by $L_1=\Bbb P^1\times \{\text{pt}\}$ and $L_2=\{\text{pt}\}\times \Bbb P^1$.
In Definition 6.3 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.14544, it is written that: Choose a smooth rational curve $E\subset X$ which is a triple section for the first projection and has exactly three ramified points $p,q,r$, where $p,q$ have order two and $r$ has order three.
My question is, how do we know the existence of such a rational curve? Since $E$ is a triple section for the first section, its homology class should be $3[L_1]$. Can we choose a rational curve in $X$ whose homology class is equal to $3[L_1]$? Also how can we handle the ramification points and their orders? Is there a classification result for rational curves in $X$?
Edit. Given a complete linear system on $X$ how do we know the genus of a general member? Is there a certain formula?

@CraniumClamp Thanks. Can I find a reference or a kind of formula to obtain such results?

I wrote a full answer now.

If $ D \subset \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 $ is an ample divisor of type $ (a,b) $, this is equivalent to having  $ a,b \ge 1 $ and the formula for the arithmetic genus of $ D $ is $ g(D) = (a-1)(b-1) $. This comes from the adjunction formula $ 2g(D) - 2 = D \cdot (D + K_{\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1}) $ by substituting $ D $, $ K_{\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1} = (-2,-2) $ and knowing the intersection form $ (\alpha, \beta) \cdot (\alpha', \beta') = \alpha \beta' + \alpha' \beta $. (The adjunction formula holds for $ D $ smooth but the arithmetic genus is constant in flat families, so a degeneration argument gives the full result)
If the curve $ D $ is a triple section for the first projection, this does not mean its homology class is $ 3[L_1] $. All it means that any line of the form $ pt \times \mathbb{P}^1 $ intersects $ D $ in three points (counting intersection multiplicities). That is to say $ (0,1)\cdot(a,b) = 3 \implies a = 3 $.
A general member of the linear system of type $ (3, b) $ with $ b \ge 1 $ is smooth and has genus $ g(D) = 2(b-1) $ so we must be choosing $ b =1 $ to get a curve of genus $ 0 $. (Members in the linear system of type $ (3,0) $ don't work obviously, for your purposes)
Now the first projection $ p_1 : D \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1 $ is a degree $ 3 $ map so applying Riemann-Hurwitz gives $ -2 = 3(-2) + \deg R \implies \deg R = 4 $. Here $ R \subset D $ is the ramification divisor. The map is given by two homogenous degree $ 3$ polynomials $ P, Q $. Generical situation (1) $ P $ and $ Q $ are going to have simple zeroes therefore the critical points are on the open set where $ Q $ doesn't vanish, i.e., we're trying to find critical points of $ z \rightarrow p(z)/q(z) $, where $ P, Q $ are now dehomogenized to $ p,q $ of degree 3. But the critical points are the zeroes of $ p'(z) q(z) - p(z) q'(z) $ which is a polynomial of degree 4 (why?). Therefore, generical situation (2) there are going to be $ 4 $ critical points, the zeroes of the degree $ 4 $ polynomial above, each with index $ 2 $.
We may now specialize to a case when there are $ 3 $ critical points, which corresponds to $ p'(z)q(z) - p(z) q'(z) $ having two simple roots and one repeated root with multiplicity $ 2 $, hence with indices $ 2,2 $ and $ 3 $ respectively. This is the desired situation.
